# How to pass a input parameter to a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

I have to execute a PowerShell script with a PowerShell command. In the script, which is called, there is a user input at the beginning. In the function there is one parameter for the password:

```
    param(
    [Parameter(Position=1,mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $Password)
```

Does anyone know how can I pass the password to this script?

I tried it that way, however, it did not work:

Powershell.exe -File "C:\Projects\installation.ps1" -Password test1234*

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Any error message? Please edit your question to include such details.

Comment: Nothing happened. The user input appeared anyway.

Comment: So it worked? Or it prompted you to provide an input value for Password?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes exactly I was prompted for an input.

Comment: @loris02 Please show us the whole script

Comment: Works like a charm

`powershell -nonInteractive -file s:\passParamTest.ps1 xoxo*`
`powershell -nonInteractive -file s:\passParamTest.ps1 -Password xoxo*`
Code:
`param([Parameter(Position=1,mandatory=$true)][string] $Password) Write-Host "PS is $($Password)"`

Comment: Possibly the problem is in another line. Add `-NonInteractive` flag to `powershell.exe` to see the exact line where it fails